# How to get all table counts from database in JSON output in TSQL script

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to have a TSQL script to output all table counts from a SQL Server database to a JSON file. Getting the table counts is not the problem, but outputting this to JSON is the issue. I can't get it to work.

This is what I have to get the table counts:

```
USE databasename
GO

SELECT
      QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(sOBJ.schema_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(sOBJ.name) AS [TableName]
      , SUM(sPTN.Rows) AS [RowCount]
FROM 
      sys.objects AS sOBJ
      INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS sPTN
            ON sOBJ.object_id = sPTN.object_id
WHERE
      sOBJ.type = 'U'
      AND sOBJ.is_ms_shipped = 0x0
      AND index_id < 2 -- 0:Heap, 1:Clustered
GROUP BY 
      sOBJ.schema_id
      , sOBJ.name
ORDER BY [TableName]

GO
```

How can I output the results to JSON?

Comment: What about the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) on the subject didn't you understand? Where did you get stuck in your attempt to implement the functionality?

Comment: Does adding `for json auto` not give you the desired output?

Comment: I tried that but I get errors whatever I try. I seriously don't know where to put it in the script. If you could tell me where it should go in the script I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a simple resultset to Json, add `for json auto` to the end of the statement eg,

```
...GROUP BY 
      sOBJ.schema_id
      , sOBJ.name
ORDER BY [TableName]
FOR JSON AUTO
```

See this [example DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ac69313313b05f3e0563643278da0424)